# How to write API data to a computer file?

Tags: api

I've never used an API before. I want to start using an API that gives me prices and characteristics of items in an online game. I'm in the processing of learning how to create the API that will be able to extract the available information from a specific website which has such information.

Here's my question: after extracting the information from the website using the API, I also want to download the information for analysis. For example, it would be nice if I could download the data as an excel file or CSV file format that I can later import. Do you know how I can do that?

Let me know if the question is still too vague.

Comment: I don't think you've quite grasped what "API" means.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what an API means:

API, an abbreviation of application program interface, is a set of routines, protocols, and tools for building software applications. The API specifies how software components should interact and are used when programming graphical user interface (GUI) components.  A good API makes it easier to develop a program by providing all the building blocks. A programmer then puts the blocks together.

Generally you recieve data from the API as JSON(Java Script Object Notation) or as a XML file.I would prefer JSON because it gives programmers great flexibility while writing codes.

I could not make out what Language are using but here's the general algorithm that I would go about:

1.Call the API with the required paramters generally POST Data

2.Receive the data from the API as JSON or XML

3.Parse the data

4,Use the CSV library for your language

5.Write data to your CSV file

6.End

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I know that the developers of the website uses JSON to share their app's features. Do you know how I can use the CSV library and write data to my CSV file? I've never done either before that's why i'm asking...